# firebase express-session dosn't store nothing in the cookies

Tags: node.js, firebase, cookies, firebase-realtime-database, express-session

This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const FirebaseStore = require('connect-session-firebase')(session);
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const ref = firebase.initializeApp(
  functions.config().firebase
);

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(session({
  store: new FirebaseStore({
    database: ref.database()
  }),
  secret: 'abigsigrettotheseeiosnofthmbiith765huig',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session);
  req.session.username='xyz';
  res.send('Filling the session with data');
});

app.get('/bar', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session);
  var sessionData = req.session.username;
  res.send(`This will print the attribute I set earlier: ${sessionData}`);
});


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When I run this, it creates new session in the DB.

And every time I refresh the page, there is a new session.

I want of course, that only one session would be created,

and that on refresh, this session would only be updated, or to get the data from there. not to create a new one every time.

Checking the cookies - showed me that no cookie is saved / created.

I've been working on this for hours...

Answer (score 0):

this was frustrating when I was using firebase functions and hosting, but can be solved by simply setting `name:"__session"` in the session.

```
app.use(session({
  store: new FirebaseStore({
    database: ref.database()
  }),
  name:"__session
  ...
```